# Nonzero function help, Python Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I have two arrays, and I have a complex condition like this: `new_arr<0 and old_arr>0`
I am using nonzero but I am getting an error. The code I have is this:

```
    indices = nonzero(new_arr<0 and old_arr>0)
```

I tried:

```
    indices = nonzero(new_arr<0) and nonzero(old_arr>0)
```

But it gave me incorrect results.

Is there any way around this? And is there a way to get the common indices from two nonzero statements. For example, if:

```
    indices1 = nonzero(new_arr<0)
    indices2 = nonzero(old_arr>0)
```

and these two indices would contain:

```
   indices1 = array([0, 1, 3])
   indices2 = array([2, 3, 4])
```

The correct result would be getting the common element from these two (in this case it would be the element 3). Something like this:

```
    result = common(indices1, indices2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `indices = nonzero((new_arr < 0) & (old_arr > 0))`:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: old_arr = np.array([ 0,-1, 0,-1, 1, 1, 0, 1])

In [7]: new_arr = np.array([ 1, 1,-1,-1,-1,-1, 1, 1])

In [8]: np.nonzero((new_arr < 0) & (old_arr > 0))
Out[8]: (array([4, 5]),)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Never came to my mind using & instead of the good old and. Thanks!

Comment: +1, but only works if both input arrays are of the same shape (OP didn't mention any such assumption).

Comment: @Radim: No such assumptions were mentioned, but if you're talking about "common indices", then you'd just end up resizing the larger array to the dimensions of the smaller one anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
indices = nonzero(logical_and(new < 0, old > 0))
```

(Thinking about it, my previous example wasn't all that useful if all it did was return `nonzero(condition)` anyway.)

Comment: I dont' understand what you mean with condition.nonzero()